# Unable to highlight tab character when individually selected in QML TextArea

Tags: qml, textarea, highlight

I'm using the `TextArea` component in QML for text editing. There's an issue: when I try to select a single tab (`\t`) character, it doesn't get highlighted. The problem is that the tab character doesn't show up as selected when I try to select it individually.

Here's a code example:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600

    TextArea {
        id: textArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        text: "Tab" + "\t" + "Highlighting" + "\t" + "Issue"
        selectionColor: "lightblue"
        font.pixelSize: 18
    }
}
```

When I attempt to select a single tab character (by directly highlighting it with the mouse or using Shift + arrow keys), the tab character doesn't change color. However, if I select the tab along with other text, it gets highlighted properly. Is there a way to make sure that even a single tab character gets highlighted when I select it on its own?

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-78199

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a workaround by calculating and drawing the selection yourself with `positionToRectangle()` calls, e.g.

```
TextArea {
    id: textArea
    anchors.fill: parent
    text: "Tab" + "\t" + "Highlighting" + "\t" + "Issue"
    selectionColor: "transparent" //"lightblue"
    property rect startRect: positionToRectangle(selectionStart)
    property rect endRect: positionToRectangle(selectionEnd)
    font.pixelSize: 18
    background: Item {
        Rectangle {
            x: textArea.startRect.x
            y: textArea.startRect.y
            width: textArea.endRect.x - textArea.startRect.x
            height: textArea.endRect.height
            color: "lightblue"
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: select(3, 4)
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAC/HicjZJNT4QwEIbv/IqG027U7kFP3MzGxL3tKkcvBUZotrTYDhFi+O+2gF1AzNoLdOaZr3fKy0ppJCc81Tw9B3x2pXslUSthgiPLgXwFxJ4jw7SALIYGHzWw0eoOzyKCo9kbmUwLpQ1950JEpGIaJHqnAQEpciX3SigdkVDwvMBE1BB6xmW0npglIbkh4Rv2n2cL9jCX+dR+MGYavFd2IGlLUlejrAQg2C6Hupv7W/Kw7dku6IJgt1sORz9KsdDkT4kWgvwSo9KqAo0t0bY0Mcg0vtg/q4ky3GkQK3dnMhew8cK8Om67kgBk9o/wJ5kNwQlLz7lWtbRtHRDKydp82MTmTnMZgPp2aTNj2lWmnTGfPMNiwo2d04bcXS9QgFvySvTgmLHp8IguOWevy6Pdz8a/AQBj7hM=)

Reference:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#positionToRectangle-method